# How to implement the ability to share text/media into a chat app in Swift/ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

I have developed an iPhone chat application using a combination of Swift 2.3 and Objective C.
The chat application has a typical set of features like contacts, chat threads (rooms), sending and receiving text and binary content, etc.
I want to implement the ability to send text and binary information into the app (Share functionality), such that my users can share URLs, text and images from 3rd party apps like Safari, Photos, etc., into my app.

How can this be done? Is there sample code or an example or a tutorial someplace?

Like so:
[image: How to share a photo or URL or selected text into my app, the way ti can be shared into Slack and WhatsApp?]

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a Share [App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html) in your application.

[image]

Check out [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/) (or [this one](http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/share-extension-in-ios-application-overview-with-example/) or [this other](http://www.deegeu.com/ios-share-extension-with-swift/)) for a full example. More info in [the Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UIActivityViewController` to implement the share functionality. For that you have to import the `Social` framework.

Eg:

```
import Social
.....
.....

let string: String = ...
let URL: NSURL = ...

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[string, URL], applicationActivities: nil)
navigationController?.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true) {
// ...
}
```

For more information you can refer [this url](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)

Comment: He doesn't want to share content, he wants to allow others share content with his app.